# starting a vaadin application with vaadinCDI makes exception

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, vaadin, netbeans-8, apache-tomee

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.vaadin.cdi.internal.AnnotationUtil.getUiBeans(AnnotationUtil.java:80)
        at com.vaadin.cdi.internal.ContextDeployer.discoverUIMappingsFromAnnotations(ContextDeployer.java:109)
        at com.vaadin.cdi.internal.ContextDeployer.contextInitialized(ContextDeployer.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4772)

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-cdi</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

at any version: 
1.0.0.beta4/1.0.0.alpha2/1.0.0.alpha3

at any combinations of ide (eclipse luno / netbeans 8.0.2 / eclipse)
at any combination of containers ( tomee-plus 2)
vaadin version 7.3.6/7.4.0-rc1

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, your `web.xml` and your main UI class.

Comment: Have you tried stable releases? Newest version is 1.0.2. Just to check, do you have a beans.xml?

Comment: I have started in tomee using NetBeans now. @geert3 There is no web.xml in the project.

Comment: @KimL could be because of the alpha versions, however, it works, let me say, "out-of-the-box" on import project to IntelliJ IDEA 14 30-days trial using maven config. 

`\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\beans.xml` :

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>` are there wrong namespaces?

Comment: The beans.xml can actually be completely empty, the file just needs to exist.

Comment: Actually Kim L approach is resolving the issue.